# Possible API authorization techniques on a fintech/banking app

Tags: rest, api, security, authentication, authorization

Let's assume that we've implemented a RESTful API providing financial/banking services and want to provide it to an in-house development team to implement the native mobile client-app.

In that sense the app and therefore the API will be **public** and reachable, so the **WHAT** gets access to it, needs to be authorized in every possible way.

The first solution that comes to mind is to provide a **client_id** and a **client_secret** and let the developers sign every request with the use of an Authorization http header:

```
Authorization: APP client_id:base64(HMAC-SHA256(content, client_secret))
```

As long as the server "knows" the client's secret, authorization of API usage will run smoothly.

What I do not like about this:

- every app instance out there has the same client_secret
- the client_secret is irrevocable
- it can be easily exposed through the app's source code even being obfuscated
- all in all, possibility of getting requests from unknown sources

On the other hand I do not want to mess with user experience, with redirects and extra login requests like OAuth and such.

What other authorization techniques are there for this kind of apps? Which path for authorization do famous fintech/banking companies follow?

Comment: I assume the User has to authenticate himself/herself to you (your backend) somehow. So if the User does that, why do you need to authenticate the client? I assume you validate everything on the backend, and check whether the authenticated user is allowed to do what the client submits. I don't see why the client matters. Am I missing something?

Comment: Also, anything distributed with the client app should be considered effectively public.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam correct, user authentication is in place. I want to be sure that the client is "what" it is supposed to be. How can I be sure of that? What about endpoints that are not user authenticated like registering or going a bit further with providing the API to 3rd parties and throttling etc.

Answer (score 2):

Do not authenticate the app, authenticate the user or entity using it.

Endpoints like "register" that do not need authentication, well, do not need authentication. You can throttle access independent of an authentication too, based on networks the traffic is coming from, etc. This is usually done in the infrastructure, you do not have to have code for this.

In general, from a security standpoint, published clients should be regarded as user-controlled. I.e. the data they generate should be regarded as entirely user-controlled too, even if signed, obfuscated or whatever.

So far you didn't mention any use-case from the point of the backend, where authenticating the client software somehow would add value.

I did actually work on a banking backend which was accessed through an app and a web-ui (and several admin-uis). We didn't care which ui the user was using in the backend, we authenticated the user only. Things that did not need authentication (country lists, address/iban resolvers, etc.) were usable without one. I don't even know if the access was throttled or controlled in operation, it was not our job.

Comment: Say you provide an API which is like you mentioned, open. And you charge per request. What happens then? It doesn't matter. The question is if there is another way to implement client authorization. Yes you authenticate the user to know who is requesting but what about the what is requesting. Especially for banking apps, there's supposed to be an auth scheme for compliance I suppose. I can't imagine me playing with Revolut endpoints using a REST client app or can I.

Comment: I'm located in the EU, worked for multiple financial institutions in multiple countries, I'm not aware of any compliance issues regarding authenticating the app in addition to the user. You could in fact, and we did, test our own API with curl, soapui and such. If you charge per request, you in general have to know *who* you charge, regardless *what* they use for access. Maybe I'm just missing your point.